# Thales HSM - Windows cp 1252 succes / Linux UTF-8 Fail

Tags: java, linux, utf-8, hsm

I am working on TCP/IP Application with HSM Module Integration. 
My JAVA code was working fine in Windows 32 bit/JRE 32 Bit/IBM Websphere 7, 
When i upgrade to RedHat Linux-64 bit/JRE 64 bit/IBM webshere 8, If i sending below 127 length of the string was working fine, but more than 127 it was returning the response. Also I have done some encoding techniques, but facing the same pblm pls guide me .

If the commandLength = less than 127, working fine, but it was > than 127 [ UTF-8 encoding was failing ]
So for more than 127 i am using extended ascii, but it was not working in the [UTF-8]/working fine in windows-1252
//hsmMessage.insert(0, (char)commandLength);

```
         char[] extended_ascii = new char[1];           
         byte cp437bytes[]= new byte[1];                
         cp437bytes[0] = (byte) commandLength;      
         extended_ascii = new String(cp437bytes).toCharArray();     //extended_ascii = new String(cp437bytes, "CP437").toCharArray();
         hsmMessage.insert(0, extended_ascii);
```

Thanks

Comment: post some code you have tried.

Comment: The fact that you use `String`s to exchange encrypted data is already suspect by itself. Post the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use `String` objects to hold arbitrary binary data - use `byte` arrays or wrappers thereof.

The reason is that when converting from a byte array to a String the given locale is used to convert the bytes into Character objects which will in many circumstances end up with the String not holding the exact bytes you think it should, especially for byte values >= 128.

I had a very similar problem many years ago in the RADIUS server I had written.  It would work fine for the vast majority of passwords, but if a user password had a `£` symbol in it the differences between US-ASCII and UK-ASCII caused the underlying byte value to get mangled, resulting in mis-calculated encrypted passwords, and failed logins.